# Why do malloc and free have different return types?

Tags: c, pointers

Declarations look like these:

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
void free(void *pointer)
```

As far as I can understand, the void *malloc means that malloc returns a pointer to void ("Void pointer") and free is just void. What's the difference? Why does it look this way?

Comment: `malloc` allocates something and returns you that block, `free` deallocates the block and... nothing more. Why should it return something at all?

Comment: If you think it through, what did you expect free() to return? A pointer to an invalid, deallocated memory segment on the heap?

Comment: He clearly can't see the difference between `void*` and `void`

Comment: So are you saying that it's inconceivable that also malloc could be just void and doesn't have to be void *? I do understand the difference between void * and void when it comes to arguments/parameters but I'm long into OOP so I might be expecting something that I can't if I don't get a pointer to the allocated memory. I could think that malloc could be just void and then you get the address of the allocated memory from the variable instead of the return value. Would that be crazy?

Comment: "you get the address of the allocated memory from the variable instead of the return value" -- what variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `void` just means the return type isn't defined (not a pointer to a `char`, for example), just a contiguous block of memory of specified size.

`free()` doesn't return anything. It doesn't need to.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` returns a pointer (`void*`) to the allocated memory. `free` frees the memory. It doesn't return anything (`void`).

Answer (score 2):

`void pointer` is generic pointer. This can be assigned to any type of pointer. so malloc is designed in such that way.

free() is not going to return anything. simply de-allocates the block of memory with given address entry from heap.

Answer (score 2):

They are not equivalent to each other. Why compare?

malloc allocates memory so it should return the pointer to the aloocated memory.

free deallocates the memory and it doesn't have to return any value, so it's void.

Comment: I compared since both returned void. I didn't understand the difference between void and pointer to void. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: it isn't "void and pointer", it is "void pointer" (untyped pointer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with C is that in this case, it is weakly typed. You cannot malloc an array of ints, chars, doubles, or any other struct - there would have to be a malloc/free pair for any type possible (including your own structs). So instead of returning a pointer to some type, the pointer has the void type. That means, the type of the data is undetermined, and you usualy cast that pointer to the type pointer you need.

The common usage pattern of malloc therefore is:

```
type *myMemory = (type *)malloc(x * sizeof(type));
```

where type is the type you want to malloc (int, char, struct...) and x is the number of "instances"you want to malloc.

The free method just takes the pointer from malloc and frees it. Following the same logic, it cannot take an int, char... pointer, so it takes void pointer. Void pointer is "compatible" with any other pointer.

Comment: Another common usage is type* M = malloc( x*sizeof *M); this is better because when you change the type of M you don't need to remember to change the argument of malloc.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely differet things. The fact that they look similar is just down to the syntax used.

"void *" is a pointer to a block of memory without any particular type associated with it. You can cast it to any other pointer type.

"void" (without the star) means that the function doesn't return any value at all.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` is a memory allocation function which primary job is to `return pointer to starting address of the memory block` allocated by malloc() .The problem is that `malloc()` is designed to be generic not for the any `single` type so,the `address return should not be for a specific type` (e.g char,int) ,it should be generic so `malloc()` returned a void pointer which is giving an option to programmer to cast it to any type and use that memory. so its return type is void *.

For `free()`,it a memory freeing function which primary job is to `free the content of the memory address pointed by the argument`,This also designed for generic by which it can able to free any memory type not for only char,int etc.so its argument type is void *.

free returning nothing means that is a void not any pointer or any thing else,so it simply void.

Answer (score 0):

`void*` means "any type pointer". Points to memory which type is not defined or not important at that particular moment.

`void` is plain nothing. No value.

`printf("malloc returned address %p\n", malloc(1));` is valid C, `malloc` returns a pointer to a block of memory containing undefined data.

`printf("free returned status %d\n",free(ptr));` is not valid C because `free` does not actually return anything.